# PHP - How to tell if a page is being used

Tags: php, mysql, web, content-management-system, wysiwyg

So I essentially have a WYSIWIG editor on a website.

I want to be able to tell if a user is currently editing a page, to prevent other users from entering it while it is "busy".

I implemented a system that marked articles as busy in mySQL. When a user would enter the page to edit it, it would mark it as busy, and it would be unmarked by binding a function to **window.onbeforeunload**.

However, window.onbeforeunload does not get called if the page is closed unexpectedly, such as if the browser crashes or is force closed. This results in some articles being marked as busy when they shouldn't be.

Is there a more proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the page regularly (e.g. once every 10 seconds) requests a "keepalive" page (include the current time in the URL, so the pages don't get cached!), and the last timestamp is kept in the database, then you can have a timeout - any "open" page that hasn't had a "keepalive" requested for, say, 30 seconds, is probably no longer open.

Comment: Keeping the last timestamp is a good idea. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most portable way would be to mark the page as "busy" when the edit page loads, and unmark it after some time has passed (maybe 3 minutes).  Then, make an AJAX request every minute or so that renews the busy mark.  This way, as long as the page is open and AJAX requests are being made, the page will be marked busy.

You can still keep the onbeforeunload event handler to unmark the page if the browser supports this, but if the browser doesn't then it will get unmarked no later than 3 minutes after the user closes the page.

Comment: So I would have to setup a cron to mark all pages as not busy repeatedly. And wouldn't it cause lapses, where the page would switch from busy to not busy repeatedly?

Comment: @Nikzilla Not if the timeout (3 minutes as an example) is longer than the poll frequency (1 minute).  You'd expect a poll every 3 minutes, which would reset the time.  You wouldn't need a cron job at all, just use a query something like: `SELECT ..., (CASE WHEN busy_date IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE DATE_ADD(busy_date, INTERVAL 3 minutes) <= NOW() END) AS is_busy`.  You'd `UPDATE ... SET busy_date = NOW()` every time the AJAX request is made.  The `CASE` frees you from having to clear any marker; you just check to see how long ago the mark was set.